# Odoo 10 Kanban view hide "Add new Column"

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

I upgraded Odoo from 9 to 10 version and have a problem with Kanban view. I can't hide "Add new column" menu. On 9 version this menu I did not notice...

Tried this method on xml:

```
        <kanban position="attributes">
            <attribute name="group_create">false</attribute>
        </kanban>
```

But it doesn't help me. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following, Do not forget to add  `<field name="mode">primary</field>`

```
        <record id="project_issue_view_kanban_inherit_no_group_create" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">project.issue.view.kanban.inherit.no.group.create</field>
            <field name="model">project.issue</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="project_issue.project_issue_kanban_view"/>
            <field name="mode">primary</field>
            <field name="priority">32</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <kanban position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="group_create">false</attribute>
                </kanban>
            </field>
        </record>
```